# Why does this code leak when the memory allocation is cross thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, memory-leaks

First off, this is running on OSX, compiled in xcode. I have tried both clang and g++, both show the same symptoms. Basically, there are two lines in this sample, one allocates and frees a buffer in the worker thread, and the other allocates the buffer in the main thread, and frees it in the worker thread. The in-thread alloc works fine, but the cross thread alloc causes the total memory used by the process (viewed using top) to increase by 4k bytes every time the buffer is retrieved on the worker thread. What gives here? The heap should be global to all threads in the process and no marshaling should be occuring here, so why is the process memory increasing?

Valgrind reports no leaks in both cases, and reports the same number of allocations and frees in both cases. However, the process memory is clearly increasing in one versus the other.

The sample code is stripped down to show the basics:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>

class CNetworkBuffer
{
public:
    uint32_t MaxSize;
    uint32_t Size;
    uint8_t *Data;

    CNetworkBuffer()
    {
        printf("Creating new network buffer: %d %d\n", 0, 0);
        Size = 0;
        MaxSize = 0;
        Data = NULL;
    }

    CNetworkBuffer(uint32_t size, uint32_t maxSize)
    {
        printf("Creating new network buffer: %d %d\n", size, maxSize);

        MaxSize = maxSize;
        Size = size;
        Data = new uint8_t[MaxSize];
    }

    ~CNetworkBuffer()
    {
        printf("Deleting network buffer of size %d (%d) %p\n", Size, MaxSize, Data);
        if(Data != NULL)
        {
            delete[] Data;
            Data = NULL;
        }
    }
};

class CNetworkBuffers
{
public:

    //
    // Public constructor
    //
    CNetworkBuffers()
    {
    }

    //
    // Public destructor
    //
    ~CNetworkBuffers()
    {
        while(!m_buffers.empty())
        {
            CNetworkBuffer *p = m_buffers.front();
            m_buffers.pop_front();
            delete p;
        }
    }

    //
    // Initializes the total number of buffers in this cache and the size of
    // each buffer
    //
    void Initialize(uint32_t numBuffers, uint32_t bufferSize)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numBuffers; ++i)
        {
            m_buffers.push_back(new CNetworkBuffer(0, bufferSize));
        }
    }

    //
    // Retrieves a new buffer from the list of free buffers. This call blocks if there
    // are no free buffers.
    //
    std::shared_ptr<CNetworkBuffer> GetBuffer()
    {
        m_cs.lock();

        if(m_buffers.size() > 0)
        {
            CNetworkBuffer *pBuffer = m_buffers.front();
            m_buffers.pop_front();
            printf("Retrieving buffer: %p\n", pBuffer);
            m_cs.Unlock();
            return std::shared_ptr<CNetworkBuffer>(pBuffer);
        }
        else
        {
            assert(false);
        }

        m_cs.unlock();
    }

private:

    //
    // The list of free buffers in this class.
    //
    std::list<CNetworkBuffer*> m_buffers;
    std::mutex m_cs;
};

static void *
ThreadFunc(void *p)
{
    CNetworkBuffers *buffers = (CNetworkBuffers *)p;
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
    {
        //
        // NOTE: This type of allocation works fine
        //
        std::shared_ptr<CNetworkBuffer> buffer(new CNetworkBuffer(0, 1024));

        //
        // NOTE: Comment out the previous line and uncomment out this one,
        //       and watch as the process memory grows.
        //
        //std::shared_ptr<CNetworkBuffer> buffer = buffers->GetBuffer();

        printf("Retrieved buffer of size %d (%d) - %d\n", buffer->Size, buffer->MaxSize, i);
        sprintf((char *)buffer->Data, "%s", "DEADBEEF");
        sleep(1);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    printf("Allocating memory for buffers\n");
    CNetworkBuffers buffers;
    buffers.Initialize(64, 1024);

    // Now create another thread to read use those buffers
    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, ThreadFunc, &buffers);
    pthread_join(t, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have double free problem. try to search 'rule of three'

Comment: @billz Won't valgrind report the double free problem?

Comment: The first thing I would do is change m_buffers to be a std::list<std::shared_ptr<CNetworkBuffer> > rather than a list of raw pointers.  Raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects are an invitation for memory leaks.